How can i add classpath in the Android studio jellyfish version?
dependencies {

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'

}
I need to add this part to the gradle, but I don't know where to add the class path part in the jellyfish version.
If anyone knows how to apply it in the jellyfish version, please share the information..
this is my build.gradle.kts(Project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-            projects/modules.
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false

}

classpath dependency declarations are old and outdated. They have been replaced by implementation years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47049984/150978

Are you still stuck with the above problem or you found the solution?
